# Java LinkedHashMap : 2 / 3 dimensional array

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

like to know how to use LinkedHashMap to store data which is like

```
Sector 1 will have

           Block 1 , 
                //Block will have Entry 1, 2,3 ... n values
                Entry 1,
                Entry 2,
                Entry 3,
                ........
                Entry n,

           Block 2 ,
                Entry a,
                Entry b,
                .......
                Entry n
           .....
           .....
           Block n
                Entry x
                Entry y
                 .....
                Entry n            

Sector 2 will have

           Each Sector will have Block 1, 2, 3 .... n

               Each  Block has Entry 1, 2, 3 .... n values
```

I tried to have 2 dimensional array to hold Block and Entry and key is the Sector
LinkedHashMap

I dont know how to use put() and get() method of LinkedHashMap. I tried searching web, cant get much information of multiple dimension arrays in HashMap

Appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashMap<LinkedHashMap<Block, List<Entry>>>` - API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), if you want to retain key entry order . Or a `TreeMap<TreeMap<Block, List<Entry>>>` - API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), if you need to maintain order of keys based on comparison or natural order .

Comment: make a class key, with  fields, Sector and Block, overide methods `hashCode` and `equals` then just create map `LinkedHashMap<CustomKeyClass, List<Entry>>` it will be worth if you wrap it into some util which combines entry and convert them into key or automatically create new list when you insert firs entry. but this is minor details

Comment: @Mena,  I have to maintain the key order.  it should be LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Block, List<Entry>>>, right?

Comment: @SKay `TreeMap<TreeMap<Block, List<Entry>>>` and implement `Comparable<Block>` / `Comparable<Entry>` in respective classes to provide a `compareTo` method that will compare based on their index property. If you have to just maintain insertion order with no sorting/indexing, `LinkedHashMap<LinkedHashMap<Block, List<Entry>>>` will do just fine.

Comment: @Mena, i have to main insertion order with no sorting/indexing. In this LinkedHashMap<LinkedHashMap<Block, List<Entry>>>, where is they key. i think key is mapping to Block and List Entry